# Kotlin - Can not send query data to service correctly

Tags: android, rest, kotlin, retrofit

I am trying build an app using Coin Gecko API. I am using specific service called /api/v3/coins/{id}. For example, the id of the BTC coin is "bitcoin". So the request should be something like that; "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin". But, I am getting an error. My request's URL is "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/%7Bid%7D?id=bitcoin". Why this part of string is added to the url? `(%7Bid%7D?id=)`

```
@GET("/api/v3/coins/{id}")
    suspend fun getCoinsDetail(
        @Query("id") id: String?
    ) : Response<CoinsDetailResponse>
```

I tried this block of code. Also, I tried with `@BODY` annotation instead of `@Query` annotation. But, this time I got the error:

> "API does not have BODY"

Answer (score 0):

Please double check [the official documentation](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) to the `Retrofit`, it has an answer to your question:

```
@GET("group/{id}/users")
Call<List<User>> groupList(@Path("id") int groupId);
```

You have to use `@Path` instead of `@Query`. This one should work:

```
@GET("/api/v3/coins/{id}")
    suspend fun getCoinsDetail(
        @Path("id") id: String?
    ) : Response<CoinsDetailResponse>
```